# Boyle's Law Related Rates question.

Tags: calculus

Boyle's law states that when a sample of gas is compressed at a constant temperature P and volume V are related by the equation PV=C, where C is a constant. Suppose that at a certain instant the volume is 600 cm3 and the pressure is 150 kPa and is increasing at a rate of 10 kPa/min. At what rate is the volume decreasing at this instant?

Help so greatly appreciated :] Having a VERY hard time with related rates problems so I don't have any idea where to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You know $\frac{dP}{dt}=10$

Find $\frac {dP}{dV}$.

Then you get

$\frac {dP}{dV}=\frac{dP}{dt}.\frac{dt}{dV}$

or $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dP}{dt}.\frac{dV}{dP}$

Aliter:

$PV=C$

Differentiate it with respect to $t$, you get $\frac{dP}{dt}.V+\frac{dV}{dt}.P=0$

Answer (score 2):

Start by differentiating both sides of $PV=C$ with respect to $t$, using the product rule for the product on the left hand side. You're given the values of $V$, $P$, and $dP/dt$, and from the equation you get by differentiating, you can get $dV/dt$.